# Find between &gt; and &lt; SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, encoding

Hello I'm working on the internal search engine for my website that contains some articles. I need to find keywords into my articles that are saved in my database in a HTML encoded format.

For example this could be an article on my database

```
&lt;/h2&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;color:#FF0000;&quot;&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit 
amet&lt;/span&gt;, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nec elit quis urna laoreet venenatis. 
&lt;em&gt;Vestibulum&lt;/em&gt; a erat orci. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nunc pulvinar,
felis vel facilisis commodo, lectus sem accumsan ante, non vestibulum ligula lorem nec leo. 
In nec elit at dolor aliquam consequat sed sed leo. Nulla facilisi. Fusce id turpis magna. 
&lt;span style=&quot;background-color:#FFFF00;&quot;&gt;
```

The human readable text is allways between **&gt** and **&lt**, so I need to find keywords within that text. To do this I need a query like:

```
SELECT title, (human readable content) FROM articles WHERE (human readable content) LIKE '%keyword%'
```

And I need to display some human readable contant without html format as description...like on google descriptions.

How can I do it?

Comment: Why not use an actual search engine? There are free ones (like Solr) that are explicitly made for stuff like this.

Comment: You *could* use [UDFs that implement regex replace](https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp) to get a crude form of sanitation. Replace `'&lt;[\s\S]*?&gt;'` with the empty string. ([via](http://stackoverflow.com/q/986826/18771))

Answer (score 2):

It's not an easy task to perform such action since there's no replacing by regex in MySQL. I suppose your text could have many html tags and so you wish to strip them all. If it is so and you're planning to do it in SQL - then good luck with [stored procedures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html).

You may want to perform some serial replaces with [LOCATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate), [SUBSTR()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) and [REPLACE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) - but with various success - looking to your sample I see that there's no solid condition to apply them (and that's why I'm not suggesting sample SQL-code).

The *correct* solution in my opinion will be do that *in application* - for example, in PHP there's [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) which will easily resolve your issue (you'll need, however, restore them from `&gt;` and `&lt;` - but that's an easy task) If it's not PHP, refer to the corresponding language manual.

Comment: Agree. This is trivial in a language that supports preg_match, but a pain in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

SQL is great for many tasks, but regex replacing/matching is not necessarily one of them. You should consider moving that part into your application business logic as it would be much easier.

If you can put the human readable part of your text into a separate column, this would be the easiest method. When you write your text to your database, you'd need to do regex or DOM parsing to strip out the text for adding the human readable part.  Since you want the text on the inner most HTML element and not just what's between any `&lt;` and `&gt;`, see if you can parse through the HTML DOM first before writing to your table. It may be easier to use a DOM parser than to write the parser from scratch.

Then you could do a simple SQL query for searching from the human readable column. Your original query would work:

```
SELECT title, content FROM articles WHERE content LIKE '%keyword%'
```

Make sure that your human readable column is in a full text index as it can be quite slow to search through an entire table if the data set is large without an index.